# How can I persist keyboard when tapping on another TextInput and center content?

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, keyboard, react-native

Currently here is my login form

```
<ScrollView centerContent>
   <View style={styles.container}>
       <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="email"
                                       keyboardType="email-address"
                                       value={this.state.email}
                                       onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})} />
       <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="password"
                                       secureTextEntry
                                       value={this.state.password}
                                       onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})} />
       <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
           <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.login.bind(this)}>
             <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
           </TouchableHighlight>
       </View>
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.toSignup}>
          <Text>To Signup</Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
</ScrollView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 8,
    margin: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: '#2c45ec',
    backgroundColor: '#2c45ec'
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#ffffff'
  },
  input: {
    height: 36,
    padding: 4,
    margin: 5,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 18,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#48BBEC',
    borderRadius: 8,
    color: '#48BBEC'
  }
});
```

And here is what it looks like

[image]

I have 2 issues with this code:

1. When I tap a text input, the keyboard shows up. When I tap another text input, the keyboard is dismissed. I have to tap that text input again for the keyboard to come back.
2. When I tap a text input, the keyboard shows up, but the content is not recentered, thus the keyboard covers up some of the bottom part of the login form.

I inspected the login form in the Facebook iOS app, and it can persist keyboard when tapping on another input, and dismiss keyboard when tapping elsewhere, and it can also recenter the content when the keyboard shows up.

How can I achieve similar effect of the Facebook iOS app?